# Como setar e manipular a quantidade de dígitos em uma variável do tipo inteiro com php?

Tags: php, sql

Bom dia!

Estou construindo um sistema com php/sql que trabalha com cartas o qual em uma determinada parte preciso gerar obrigatoriamente um código sequencial de 6 dígitos que será para cada carta a ser enviada.

carta 1 deverá possuir o código "000001", carta 2: "000002", carta 3: "000003", e assim por diante.

Possuo salvo no sql somente os últimos números como 1,2 e 3. Como faço para adicionar os outros 0's a esquerda limitando para o número máximo de 6 dígitos? Colocando 5 0's como 000001 ou mesmo 3 como 000143 se fosse o caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar da função str_pad do PHP, da seguinte forma:

```
$nomeDaVariavel = 1;

$nomeDaVariavel = str_pad($nomeDaVariavel, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

// Irá printar 000001 como texto
print $nomeDaVariavel;
```

O primeiro parâmetro é o texto a tratar, o segundo a quantidade final que deve ter o texto, o terceiro qual o caractere que será inserido e o quarto parâmetro é onde a inserção ocorrerá.

A sua base de dados terá que ser atualizada para o campo do tipo texto, para esta coluna, dado que 000001 não é um inteiro, por conta dos zeros à esquerda. Ou, terá que realizar o tratamento em todos os pontos que necessitam ser exibidos o zero à esquerda.

Comment: Opa, valeu cara!